# Sonarlint plugin crashes when Eclipse is in Program Files

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarlint

I have an installation of Eclipse 2021-12 with Sonarlint installed in `C:\Program Files`.
When I launch Eclipse, ang go to Window->Preferences, Sonarlint, there are no rules.
In the console, I have this error message below. If I copy/paste the eclipse folder from `Program Files` to `C:\Users\xxx\` and I launch it from there, I don't have the issue.

```
Starting SonarLint for Eclipse 7.2.1.42550
Started security hotspot handler on port 64120
Starting standalone SonarLint engine 7.2.1.42550...
Unable to load plugin bundleentry://427.fwk1977915520/plugins/sonar-html-plugin-3.6.0.3106.jar
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files/eclipse-2021-12/plugins/org.sonarlint.eclipse.core_7.2.1.42550/plugins/sonar-html-plugin-3.6.0.3106.jar
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2974)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3145)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3227)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3175)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:1056)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.toPath(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:96)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.getOrCreateEngine(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:64)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.withEngine(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:104)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.getAllRuleDetails(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:128)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.ui.internal.properties.RulesConfigurationPage.loadRuleDetails(RulesConfigurationPage.java:70)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.ui.internal.properties.RulesConfigurationPage.createContents(RulesConfigurationPage.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.createControl(PreferencePage.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPageControl(PreferenceDialog.java:1433)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$8.run(PreferenceDialog.java:1196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1188)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$5.lambda$0(PreferenceDialog.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$5.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1191)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.lambda$1(OpenStrategy.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4035)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3635)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4243)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1060)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4060)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3632)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1154)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)

Unable to load plugin bundleentry://427.fwk1977915520/plugins/sonar-java-plugin-7.7.0.28547.jar
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files/eclipse-2021-12/plugins/org.sonarlint.eclipse.core_7.2.1.42550/plugins/sonar-java-plugin-7.7.0.28547.jar
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2974)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3145)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3227)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3175)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:1056)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.toPath(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:96)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.getOrCreateEngine(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:64)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.withEngine(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:104)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.getAllRuleDetails(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:128)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.ui.internal.properties.RulesConfigurationPage.loadRuleDetails(RulesConfigurationPage.java:70)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.ui.internal.properties.RulesConfigurationPage.createContents(RulesConfigurationPage.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.createControl(PreferencePage.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPageControl(PreferenceDialog.java:1433)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$8.run(PreferenceDialog.java:1196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1188)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$5.lambda$0(PreferenceDialog.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$5.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1191)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.lambda$1(OpenStrategy.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4035)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3635)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4243)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1060)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4060)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3632)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1154)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

[image: Sonar with no rules due to the crash]

Comment: This sounds like what should be a bug report to Sonar.

Answer (score 1):

this bug has been already reported here (with a temporary workaround): https://community.sonarsource.com/t/unable-to-load-plugin-sonar-secrets-plugin-1-1-0-36766-jar-when-eclipse-is-installed-in-a-directory-with-a-whitespace/57343